# Stack doesn't install correct version of Haskell base library

Tags: haskell, build, dependencies

I am fairly new to Haskell. I am trying to build a project downloaded from GitHub using stack. When I try to run `stack solver`, I get this output:

```
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: deeplearning-hs-0.1.0.2 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of deeplearning-hs-0.1.0.2)
rejecting: base-4.8.1.0/installed-075... (conflict: deeplearning-hs =>
base>=4.6 && <4.7)
rejecting: base-4.8.1.0 (global constraint requires installed instance)
rejecting: base-4.8.0.0, 4.7.0.2, 4.7.0.1, 4.7.0.0, 4.6.0.1, 4.6.0.0, 4.5.1.0,
4.5.0.0, 4.4.1.0, 4.4.0.0, 4.3.1.0, 4.3.0.0, 4.2.0.2, 4.2.0.1, 4.2.0.0,
4.1.0.0, 4.0.0.0, 3.0.3.2, 3.0.3.1 (global constraint requires ==4.8.1.0)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

The issue seems to be this "global constraint" but I'm not sure where that's coming from. I have looked through my global .cabal files and they are pretty generic--they don't seem to specify the versions of anything.

Answer (score 2):

`base` is a library bundled with GHC (the compiler). For each GHC version, there is one `base` version.

To install [`deeplearning-hs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deeplearning-hs), seems you need to satisfy `base == 4.6.*` constraint, i.e. have GHC version 7.6. Unfortunately you cannot install GHC older then 7.8 with stack AFAIK.

You can play with it locally if you change `base >=4.6 && <4.7` bounds to `base >= 4.6 && <4.8`, i.e. allow `base` coming with GHC 7.8 for example. Note, you shouldn't *remove* dependencies, you should try to *relax* the constraints (i.e. version bounds). I tried locally, and the package seems to compile with GHC 7.8. It doesn't compile with GHC 7.10 as [Foldable-Traversal-Proposal](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Prelude710/FTP) affects this package.

IMHO best way is to contact the maintainer and ask for upgrade, or even better submit a pull request, as source seems to be on GitHub ([which I did](http://matrix.hackage.haskell.org/package/deeplearning-hs)).

P.S. [I relaxed the bounds on Hackage](http://matrix.hackage.haskell.org/package/deeplearning-hs), so you can install it with GHC 7.8 without worries now.

Comment: Probably he can try editing the cabal file and see if things work with the new GHC. :)

Comment: I see. I didn't know about the GHC >= 7.8 constraint for stack. I did try editing the cabal file by commenting out the requirements for `base >=4.6 && <4.7`, and ran into the following: `Could not find module ‘Data.List’ It is a member of the hidden package ‘base-4.8.1.0’.` and same for ‘Prelude.’ Perhaps it is best to work on this one without Stack, which I guess means downloading the older version of GHC?